# Detail in Verification of Suspension-Loop Adjunction in Infinity Category Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a pointed $\infty$-category. Then, $\Sigma : \mathscr{C} \rightleftarrows \mathscr{C} : \Omega$ can be defined through $\Sigma = \operatorname{colim}( * \leftarrow X \to *)$ and $\Omega = \lim ( * \to X \leftarrow *)$.

There seems to be some part in the theory of (co-)limits and adjunctions for $\infty$-categories that I'm not understanding well enough. I wanted to verify $\Sigma \dashv \Omega$ which caused me a lot of confusions. Initially, I thought that this would be a quick computation via \begin{align*} \operatorname{map}(\Sigma x, y) &\simeq \operatorname{map}(*, y) \times_{\operatorname{map}(x,y)} \operatorname{map}(*, y) \\ &\simeq \Omega \operatorname{map}(x,y) \\ &\simeq \operatorname{map}(x,*) \times_{\operatorname{map}(x,y)} \operatorname{map}(x,*) \\ &\simeq \operatorname{map}(x, \Omega y). \end{align*}
This seems fine but to show that we get an adjunction one should really prove that $$ \operatorname{map}(\Sigma x, y) \xrightarrow{\Omega} \operatorname{map}(\Omega \Sigma x, \Omega y) \xrightarrow{\eta^*} \operatorname{map}(x, \Omega y)$$ is an equivalence where $\eta$ is induced by the universal property of $\Omega$.

I thought this was fine: We can just write out suitable comparison maps to the top equivalence chain and call it a day. However, I cannot manage to do so. Could someone spell out the details of checking that really this composite $\eta^* \circ \Omega$ yields an equivalence of mapping anima?

Comment: I think roughly the point is the following: The computation is natural and an argument similar to the 1-categorical setting while using the $\infty$-categorical Yoneda Lemma then shows that the equivalence is actually induced by a composition as I wanted. (If nobody wants to say anything else about it in the next few days, I'll write an answer.)

Comment: I think I am able to show with sufficient detail that $\Omega$ is the right adjoint of $\Sigma$ by writing both as a composition of right resp. left adjoint functors. The adjunction unit will then be a suitable composition of adjunction units, and I can show this will then yield your $\eta$ as adjunction unit. This would be a solution that does not mention your computation on mapping spaces at all however, so please let me know if that would answer your question, as it would only very indirectly show that $\eta^*\circ\Omega$ is an equivalence of mapping anima.

Comment: @DaniëlApol That sounds interesting, I'd love to see it if you have time to write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functor $\Omega$ is the composite of a bunch of functors, which I will now describe. Write $\mathsf{A}$ for the diagram $2\to 3\leftarrow 1$. The inclusion $i_3\colon *\to\mathsf{A}, *\mapsto 3$ induces a left Kan extension $\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})$ (informally sending $X\in\mathscr{C}$ to $*\to X\leftarrow*$). Write $\mathsf{Sq}$ for the category $[1]\times[1]$, but instead of $(00)$, $(01)$, $(10)$, and $(11)$, I call the objects $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$, respectively. Write $i\colon\mathsf{A}\to\mathsf{Sq}$ for the obvious inclusion. This induces a right Kan extension $\mathrm{Ran}_i\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})$. Finally, the inclusion $i_0\colon *\to\mathsf{Sq}, *\mapsto 0$ induces a restriction functor $i_0^*\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})\to\mathscr{C}$. The functor $\Omega$ is the composite
$$
\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Ran}_i}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{i_0^*}\mathscr{C}.
$$
The functor $i_0^*$ is equivalent to the limit functor $\mathrm{lim}\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})\to\mathscr{C}$ (since the limit of a diagram with an initial object equals the value at this initial object), so $i_0^*$ has the constant diagram functor $\Delta\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})$ as left adjoint. The functor $\mathrm{Ran}_i$ is right adjoint to $i^*\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})$ by definition. Finally, we claim that $\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}$ is also a right adjoint functor. Let us find a left adjoint.

Write $\mathsf{B}$ for the category $(-2)\leftarrow 2\to 3\leftarrow 1\to (-1)$. There is an inclusion $j\colon\mathsf{A}\to\mathsf{B}, n\mapsto n$. Let $F\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\to\mathscr{C}$ be the composite
$$
\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Ran}_j}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{B},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{colim}}\mathscr{C}.
$$
Informally, $F$ sends a diagram $A\to C\leftarrow B$ to $\mathrm{colim}(*\leftarrow A\to C\leftarrow B\to *)$. (This functor is informally the ''main reason'' that the left adjoint to $\Omega$ will be the suspension functor).

We claim that $F$ is left adjoint to $\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}$. Given a functor $X\colon\mathsf{A}\to\mathscr{C}$, and an object $Y\in\mathscr{C}$, the mapping anima $\mathscr{C}^\mathsf{A}(X,\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}Y)$ (an ''anima'' is a synonym for ''homotopy type'' that the cool kids sometimes use nowadays --I use it because Qi did, not because I am one of those cool kids myself) can be pictured as the anima of diagrams

[image]

where the dashed maps may be freely picked, and the solid arrows are fixed. Let $p_1\colon X_1\to *$, $p_2\colon X_2\to *$, $p_{31}\colon X_3\to*$ and $p_{32}\colon X_3\to *$ be the maps given to us in the diagram $\mathrm{Ran}_j X$, which come with homotopies $p_1\simeq(X_1\to X_3\xrightarrow{P_{31}}*) and $p_2\simeq(X_2\to X_3\xrightarrow{p_{32}}*). The anima of maps $X\to *$ is contractible, as is the anima of maps $*\to Y$. Via a pullback of the anima of diagrams as above along the inclusion of those diagrams where the maps $X_1\to *$, $X_2\to *$, $X_3\rightrightarrows *$ and the homotopies between them are given by $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_{31}$, $p_{32}$ and the homotopies between them, we get a naturally(!) equivalent anima of diagrams

[image]

Likewise, we have a natural equivalence from the above anima towards the anima of diagrams

[image]

where we no longer require the maps $*\rightrightarrows Y$ to be specified. This anima is naturally equivalent to the anima $\mathscr{C}^\mathsf{B}(\mathrm{Ran}_j X, \Delta Y)$, with $\Delta\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{B},\mathscr{C})$ the constant functor. If you want to be precise about this (for instance, if you worry about naturality), you can look at the anima of natural transformations $H\colon\mathsf{B}\times[1]\to\mathscr{C}$ for which $H(0,-)$ equals $\mathrm{Ran}_j X$ and for which $H(-,1)$ equals a diagram which is equivalent to a diagram equivalent to one in which all objects are $Y$ and all morphisms are an identity morphism on $Y$ (and we require the higher morphisms of this anima to respect these boundary conditions). This anima is equivalent to the anima of functors $\mathsf{B}\star[0]\to\mathscr{C}$ which map $\mathsf{B}$ to $\mathrm{Ran}_j X$ and map the cone point to $Y$ (and for which the higher morphisms respect these boundary condition), via standard arguments. The natural zigzag of maps comparing these two functor anima (induced by a zigzag of maps of diagram shapes, hence why it is natural) witnesses this equivalence. But, the latter subanima of functors $\mathsf{B}\star[0]\to\mathscr{C}$ that we considered is exactly the anima of diagrams we saw above.

So, we have found that this anima is naturally equivalent to  $\mathscr{C}^\mathsf{B}(\mathrm{Ran}_j X, \Delta Y)$. This in turn is by the adjunction $\mathrm{colim}\dashv\Delta$ naturally equivalent to the anima  $\mathscr{C}(\mathrm{colim}\,\mathrm{Ran}_j X, Y)=\mathscr{C}(FX,Y)$. Therefore, we see that $F$ is indeed left adjoint to $\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}$.

This means that $\Omega$ is right adjoint to the composition
$$
\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Delta}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{i^*}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{F}\mathscr{C}
$$
which we claim is the suspension functor. This boils down to showing that, for any $X\in\mathscr{C}$, the suspension $\Sigma X$ is the colimit of the diagram

[image]

The colimit of this diagram may be computed in a natural way by successively taking pushouts as indicated below:

[image]

But this makes it clear that this colimit is naturally equivalent to $\Sigma X$. Hence $\Sigma\dashv\Omega$.

Now, what about the adjunction unit? The adjunction unit of a composite of adjunctions is an approrpriate composite of adjunction units. It is not hard to compute that the adjunction unit of $F\dashv\mathrm{Lan}_{i_3}$ is given for $X\colon\mathsf{A}\to\mathscr{C}$ by the map

[image]

The adjunction unit of $i^*\dashv\mathrm{Ran}_i$ is given for $Y\colon\mathsf{B}\to\mathscr{C}$ by the map

[image]

For the adjunction $\mathrm{Lan}_{i_0}\dashv i_0^*$ and $Y\in\mathscr{C}$, the adjunction unit is simply $\mathrm{id}_Y$. So, starting with $X\in\mathscr{C}$, the adjunction unit of $\Sigma\dashv\Omega$ equals the composition
$$
X\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} X\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}\times_{\mathrm{id}}\mathrm{id}} {X\times_X X} \xrightarrow{p_1\times_{p}p_2}{*\times_{\Sigma X}*\simeq\Omega\Sigma X}
$$
where $p\colon X\to \Sigma X$ is the canonical map coming from the pushout square. But this is precisely the map $\eta\colon X\to \Omega\Sigma X$ that you were after.

Comment: Thanks for writing out this long answer and being a cool kid, Daniël. I like the definition of $\Omega$, I guess this should be the correct way of defining $\Omega$ (I remember that in the derivator approach, it was done similarly), the way I tried to make it functorial seemed to rely too much on the model of simplicial sets to me and I was looking for something different here already. What is the map $X_3 \to X_1$ that you are referring to in $p_{31}$?

Comment: Oh, those maps $p_{31}$ and $p_{32}$ do not factor like that, that is a mistake. It should say that $p_1$ factors as $X_1\to X_3\to *$, thanks for pointing it out. The reason I must give names to these maps is because the map to the terminal object is not unique, so you have to find some functorial way to make a choice or to forget your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I asked Dominik Kirstein about this who gave me the following hint.

It actually suffices to show that we have a natural equivalence $\operatorname{map}(\Sigma x, y) \simeq \operatorname{map}(x, \Omega y)$ which we have because the chain of equivalences I gave in the OP are all natural. Once we have this, an argument similar to the $1$-categorical one allows us to prove that such natural equivalences all must be induced by a "unit" map, which would be the image of $\mathrm{id}_{\Sigma x}$ under the above equivalence.

Making the 1-categorical argument work, one has to be careful and use the $\infty$-categorical Yoneda Lemma.